# SQL - Historising status changes in case records

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a record of the status changes on cases from our Oracle database.
The historised records are stored in a separate table and the 'current values' in the case in the main table.

The historised table is set up so you get which field is changed, old value, new value and dates.

I would like for the data to be set up so that I can have the statuses all from first to last in separate rows. Currently my solution is as follows:

```
SELECT 
ct.CASENUMBER
, ht.FIELD 
, ht.OLDVALUE AS Status
, ct.CREATEDDATE AS createdtime
, LAG(ht.CREATEDDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ct.CASENUMBER ORDER BY ht.CREATEDDATE ) AS Previous_time
, ht.CREATEDDATE AS modifiedtime
, ht.NEWVALUE AS Next_status
, ct.STATUS AS Last_status
, DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ct.CASENUMBER ORDER BY ht.CREATEDDATE ) AS DRANK
FROM case_table ct
JOIN history_table ht
ON ct.ID = ht.CASEID 
WHERE ht.FIELD = 'Status'
```

What I'd like to be able to use the data efficiently is to have one column for the status in chronological order, whereas now I need to use both (status and next status) or (next status and last status) in order to show the entire workflow.

EDIT:
How it looks at the moment:
[Excel sample of a couple of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqcDp.png)

I would want a CASE ID, STATUS, TIMESTAMP, NEXT STATUS
that includes the last status as a separate row with null value for next status (or similarly)
Added in a HTML Table with how I'd like for it to look where the last known status has a separate row with no known next status.

Sample data:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-06','Status','In Progress','01.02.2021  11:37:09','01.02.2021  12:14:15','01.02.2021  12:17:07','Solved','Solved','2')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-06','Status','New','01.02.2021  11:37:09','NULL','01.02.2021  12:14:15','In Progress','Solved','1')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-05','Status','In Progress','01.02.2021  11:36:52','01.02.2021  13:43:24','01.02.2021  13:46:25','Solved','Solved','3')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-05','Status','Transferred','01.02.2021  11:36:52','01.02.2021  12:08:10','01.02.2021  13:43:24','In Progress','Solved','2')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-05','Status','New','01.02.2021  11:36:52','NULL','01.02.2021  12:08:10','Transferred','Solved','1')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-80','Status','New','01.02.2021  11:32:32','NULL','01.02.2021  11:42:38','Solved','Solved','1')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-79','Status','New','01.02.2021  11:32:31','NULL','01.02.2021  11:34:35','Solved','Solved','1')
INTO Table1 (Casenumber, Field, Status, Createdtime, Previous_time, Modifiedtime, Next_status, Last_status, drank) 
VALUES ('Case-78','Status','New','01.02.2021  11:32:20','NULL','01.02.2021  11:42:58','In Progress','In Progress','1')
```

```css
table {
font-size: 12px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #999999;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
table td {
border: 1px solid #999999;
padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>CASENUMBER</th><th>FIELD</th><th>STATUS</th><th>CREATEDTIME</th><th>PREVIOUS_TIME</th><th>MODIFIEDTIME</th><th>NEXT_STATUS</th><th>LAST_STATUS</th><th>DRANK</th></tr>
<tr><td>Case-06'</td><td>Status'</td><td>Solved</td><td>01.02.2021 11:37:09'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:17:07'</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>Solved'</td><td>3'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-06'</td><td>Status'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:37:09'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:14:15'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:17:07'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>2'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-06'</td><td>Status'</td><td>New'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:37:09'</td><td>NULL'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:14:15'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>1'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-05'</td><td>Status'</td><td>Solved</td><td>01.02.2021 11:36:52'</td><td>01.02.2021 13:46:25'</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>Solved'</td><td>4'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-05'</td><td>Status'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:36:52'</td><td>01.02.2021 13:43:24'</td><td>01.02.2021 13:46:25'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>3'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-05'</td><td>Status'</td><td>Transferred'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:36:52'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:08:10'</td><td>01.02.2021 13:43:24'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>2'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-05'</td><td>Status'</td><td>New'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:36:52'</td><td>NULL'</td><td>01.02.2021 12:08:10'</td><td>Transferred'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>1'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-80'</td><td>Status'</td><td>Solved</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:32'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:42:38'</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>Solved'</td><td>2'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-80'</td><td>Status'</td><td>New'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:32'</td><td>NULL'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:42:38'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>1'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-79'</td><td>Status'</td><td>Solved</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:31'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:34:35'</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>Solved'</td><td>2'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-79'</td><td>Status'</td><td>New'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:31'</td><td>NULL'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:34:35'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>Solved'</td><td>1'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-78'</td><td>Status'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:20'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:42:58'</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>In progress'</td><td>2'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Case-78'</td><td>Status'</td><td>New'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:32:20'</td><td>NULL'</td><td>01.02.2021 11:42:58'</td><td>In Progress'</td><td>In progress'</td><td>1'</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: I've added in a sample of some cases and how they look with my current setup.

Comment: Can you convert that image to an insert statement please ? When I copy that image in my dev tool.... nothing happens ;). It would also help if you gave a printed example of what output you are expecting

Comment: Added an insert statement with the example table data and a HTML Table with how it could potentially look.